# LyX: OK button is greyed out when inserting Child Document as Input

Tags: lyx

I want to include a separate .tex file in my LyX document, but I am only able to include it as a program listing.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTDTi.png)

Comment: What version of LyX are you using? I think I remember a bug like this from a previous version to LyX so consider upgrading to the newest 2.3.x version. Also, did you select the path using the "Browse" button? If not, and if the path does not lead to a file that exists, the "OK" button will be disabled. One other thing to try: change "Input" to "Include". I'm not sure why that would make a difference but worth a shot.

Comment: By the way, welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm not sure why someone gave you a "-1". Although your question is short, there's not much you can do to improve it. Perhaps you could have said exactly the steps you took to produce your screenshot. i.e., Insert > File > Child Document. Also, please always give the versions of software you are asking questions about, and also your operating system.

Comment: Thank you very much. Updating to 2.3.6.2 resolved the issue

Comment: That's great! Thanks for confirming.